# GeoServer - GetCapabilities for two layers with one request

Tags: geoserver, getcapabilities, ows

To get capabilities I am using this WMS:

```
https://my_server/workspace/wms/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

If I want to get capabilities of one specific layer I am using WMS:

```
https://my_server/workspace/layer_name/wms/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

This is working fine.

Is it possible with one WFS request to get capabilities of two specific layers?

Or how to get capabilities from layers that are in the layer group?

Answer (score 1):

An OGC web service GetCapabilities response is more about reporting the capabilities of the service rather than the layers, feature types, coverages, observations, or processes it operates on, though it does tell you enough about the layers etc. it serves to allow you to proceed with further requests.

A WFS GetCapabilities response is no different from a WMS GetCapabilities response in giving a list of all the layers/feature types it operates on.

Consider:

> http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGID/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

More then one layer

> http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGID/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&

More than one feature type

If you want more details of the feature types a WFS operates on, then you can use a DescribeFeatureType request and omit the typename.

> http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGID/ows?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=2.0.0&outputformat=text/xml%20subtype=gml/2.1.2&

Details for all feature types provided by the service.  There is no equivalent request for a WMS.